# What is the use of services if you use the ngrx/store and effects?

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects, ngrx-store-4.0

I'm trying to add NGRX to my Angular project, but I can't tell if I still need services since components can dispatch actions. Does this mean I don't have to use any service other than ngrx/store?

Comment: You can still use services, but you don't really need them.  When you dispatch actions, you send messages to the `@ngrx/store` rather than calling service methods.

Comment: @pixelbits you don't really need them in the way that a man with a hammer doesn't need a tin-opener. An effect does not understand local component scope concerns and it's not supposed to. It is specifically designed for *external* calls and its use otherwise is strongly discouraged for very good reasons. See my answer and the NGRX docs for details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I still use services to encapsulate logic. Generally, the components talk to the services and the services talk to the store.

I have found the scope of what a service does goes beyond just storing, so removing them would put too many responsibilities / business logic into the store components.

My store is focused on simple api-like actions, which are short and easy to test, e.g

```js
  static INITIALIZE_CONFIG_REQUEST = 'INITIALIZE_CONFIG_REQUEST';
  static INITIALIZE_CONFIG_SUCCESS = 'INITIALIZE_CONFIG_SUCCESS';
  static INITIALIZE_CONFIG_FAILED  = 'INITIALIZE_CONFIG_FAILED';
  static INITIALIZE_CONFIG_TEMPLATE_ERROR  = 'INITIALIZE_CONFIG_TEMPLATE_ERROR';

  createInitializeConfigRequest() { // separate from invoking call for easier testing
    return {
      type: ConfigActions.INITIALIZE_CONFIG_REQUEST,
      httpRequest: {
        url: 'api/path/to/config',
        successAction: this.createInitializeConfigSuccess,
        failedAction: this.createInitializeConfigFailed,
        validateResponse: (data) => this.checkTemplate(data)
      }
    };
  }
  initializeConfigRequest() {  // called by config.service
    this.store.dispatch( this.createInitializeConfigRequest() );
  }

  createInitializeConfigSuccess(data) {
    const payload = data;
    return {
      type: ConfigActions.INITIALIZE_CONFIG_SUCCESS,
      payload
    };
  }

  createInitializeConfigFailed(error) {
    return {
      type: ConfigActions.INITIALIZE_CONFIG_FAILED,
      payload: {
        error
      }
    };
  }
```

With this pattern, I can more easily add middleware such as that handling httpRequest and Response validation above.

Most reductions are done via a single generic reducer which makes the assumption that payload properties correspond exactly to store properties. It's my favorite convention, because now I have one set of comprehensive tests for the generic reducer instead of n repetitive tests for n reducers.

```js
  genericActionHandler(state, action) {
    if (!action.payload) {
      return state;
    }
    const newState = {...state};
    Object.assign(newState, action.payload);
    return newState;
  }
```

Hope that gives you a feel for my architecture.

Answer (score -2):

Effects are specifically intended for interaction with APIs and other entities *external* to the application and are defined as such in the NGRX specification. They do not and *should not* have knowledge of things like local router state, life-cycle hooks and similar: they are not even aware of the *existence* of the component except where explicitly informed of some aspect of this via an action payload.

Services injected into a component on the other hand do have knowledge of these things or can be provided easily with this knowledge.

As such, when you want to do anything that is self-contained and scoped only to your internal application you use a service. When you want an action to trigger some sort of external interaction, like an API call, or opening a web socket or ssh connection, you use an effect.

Note: if you wish your service to be created and destroyed in your component, you need to define it as a provider within the component metadata, within the component itself, as a service provided at module level will be a singleton.

Additional reading:

https://medium.com/@m3po22/stop-using-ngrx-effects-for-that-a6ccfe186399

https://ngrx.io/guide/effects